# Retrofit loads POST request for quite long time and gives stackOverFlow error

Tags: android, retrofit

trying to perform POST request using Retrofit library. Doing everything as usual:

```
 interface ApiCallHelper {
    @POST("/")
    void save(@Body HashMap<String, Object> params, Callback<Response> callBack);
}
```

then call the following method:

```
   public void menuSaveClicked(){
    String url = SharedData.BASE_URL +
            "api/v1/vendors/update_profile.json";
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("userId", mPrefs.getUserId());
    params.put("accessToken",mPrefs.getToken());
    params.put("phone", aq.id(R.id.etBusinessPhone).getText());
    params.put("address", aq.id(R.id.etBusinessAddress).getText());
    params.put("name", aq.id(R.id.etBusinessContactName).getText());
    params.put("businessName", aq.id(R.id.etBusinessName).getText());
    params.put("registrationNumber", aq.id(R.id.etBusinessRegNumber).getText());
    params.put("serviceTypeIds",serviceTypeIds );
    params.put("serviceAreaIds",serviceAreaIds );
    params.put("website",aq.id(R.id.etBusinessWebsite).getText() );
    params.put("facebook",aq.id(R.id.etBusinessFacebook).getText() );
    params.put("postcode",aq.id(R.id.etBusinessPostCode).getText() );
    params.put("state_id",currentState.getId() );
    params.put("city_id",currentCity.getId() );

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .build();
    ApiCallHelper apiCallHelper = restAdapter.create(ApiCallHelper.class);

    mPD.show();
    apiCallHelper.save(params, new Callback<Response>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Response object, Response response) {
            if (mPD != null)
                mPD.hide();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            if (mPD != null)
                mPD.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

So the problem is that the call is very slow around 5-7 mins and then I get "java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB" error. 
Tried using AQuery for the same api - works fine (The reason why I don't want use it, is because AQuery sends all arrays as a single String; my api can't accept it)

Comment: try adding .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) under setEndpoint(url) and debug whether you are hitting a correct url with correct body or not.

Comment: @emma thanks, that was useful, but only works with the successful requests. In my case nothing is logged and i only see a thousands of "Suspending all threads took: 21.789ms"

Comment: Can you identify which line is the last line it hits before you see Suspending all threads error ?

Comment: and where menuSaveClicked is called ?